# Error while specifying compileSdkversion in React Native Expo App

Tags: react-native, compiler-errors, expo, android-build, build-error

I have built a **React Native** app using **Expo**. Testing works fine in the emulator, but when I try to do an Android build I have errors. When I use the command `npx expo run:android`, I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\thish\OneDrive\Desktop\MottozPrinter\node_modules\expo-modules-autolinking\scripts\android\autolinking_implementation.gradle' line: 272

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-modules-core'.
   > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
      > The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
      > Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponentInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.


2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
```

### Here is my build.gradle android configuration:

[image: build.gradle file android configuration]